# Why inner class instance variable can't mofidy the outer class instance variable,but the inner class local variable can

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

Why the `test` variable occurs compile error which inside the localClassMethod and outside the tt method,but compile is ok in tt method.
**It means inner class instance variable can't mofidy the outer class instance variable,but the inner class local variable can modify the outer class instance variable.**

```
public class Outer {
    int test = 0;

    void classMethod() {
        class localClassInMethod {
            int k = test;//compile ok
            test = 1;//compile error

            public void tt() {
                test++;//compile ok
                int m = test;//compile ok
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, you can see it is compile  ok and the inner class inside the method.

Comment: You can't set anything (except declaration) in class bodies (outside functions).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could put a class inside a method until now!

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable(){}) is a good example for you. @CoderCharmander,but can you tell me the reason for that?

Comment: @rockwe How is that setting something in a class body?

Comment: @rockwe The reason is that that's how the Java designers decided to design the language. A class contains field declarations, static and init blocks, constructors and methods. Not random executable instructions. These go into methods, constructors and init blocks.

Comment: @Sweeper Yep! They're known as [local classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3), I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Although the lines look similar, they are not the same:

```java
public class Outer {
    int test = 0; // This is a field declaration, with initializer.

    void classMethod() {
        class localClassInMethod {
            int k = test; // This is a field declaration, with initializer.
            test = 1;     // This is an assignment statement, and those are only
                          // valid inside a method body or initializer block.

            public void tt() {
                test++;       // This is a post-increment expression statement.
                int m = test; // This is a local variable declaration, with initializer.

                test = 2;     // Assignment statement is valid here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to run code to assign value `1` to field `test` when a new instance of `localClassInMethod` is created, use an instance initializer block:

```java
        class localClassInMethod {
            int k = test;
            { // Initializer block.
                test = 1; // Assignment statement is valid here.
            }

            public void tt() {
                ...
            }
        }
```

That is the same as putting the statement in every constructor:

```java
        class localClassInMethod {
            int k = test;

            public localClassInMethod() {
                test = 1; // Assignment statement is valid here.
            }

            public void tt() {
                ...
            }
        }
```